# StreamingAssets Issue- In Unity Editor 48kb but in Android it is 0b. NO DATA AT ALL

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-sqlite

I have a StreamingAssets folder in Unity, it is a 48kb db file in Unity Editor. But when I built the app in Android it became 0b file. I've tried to manually paste the db into the file folder in Android mobile and it works. So I think the problem is in the transfer code to Application.persistentdatapath. Here's my code, can you please check. Thank you so much.

```
public void Connection(){
    try{
    if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android){
        path = Application.dataPath +"/youtube.bytes";
    }
    else {
         path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/youtube.bytes";
         if (!File.Exists(path)){
            WWW load = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!assets/" + "youtube.bytes");
            while (!load.isDone){}
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, load.bytes);
         }
         .........
```

}

Comment: are you getting the correct path in this ?? print the value of path .

Comment: How can I check it in Android? What path Sir/Ma'am?

Comment: your variable 'path' print it and check if the correspoding path is poiting to your file's path

Comment: Did you find how to fix this?